# WPF CheckBox to the left of the TreeView

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

How to insert checkbox to the left of the treeviewitem (expander), so it was the same item.

Answer (score 1):

Sergo,  Here is a version using the Control Template and we have Checkboxes being placed in column 0 of the item. They should align to the left with the TreeViewItem to the right. The 'magic' piece is in the CheckboxTreeItem style where we add a WrapPanel and place it in Grid.Column='0'.

```
<Window
    x:Class="TreeViewHeaderTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1"
    Height="300"
    Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="GlyphBrush"
            Color="#444" />
        <Style
            x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle"
            TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter
                Property="Focusable"
                Value="False" />
            <Setter
                Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate
                        TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <WrapPanel
                            Background="Transparent">
                            <Path
                                x:Name="ExpandPath"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="1,1,1,1"
                                Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                                Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger
                                Property="IsChecked"
                                Value="True">
                                <Setter
                                    Property="Data"
                                    TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                    Value="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style
            x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
            <Setter
                Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border>
                            <Rectangle
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                StrokeThickness="5"
                                Stroke="Black"
                                StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                                Opacity="0" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style
            x:Key="CheckboxTreeItem"
            TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter
                Property="IsExpanded"
                Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter
                Property="IsSelected"
                Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter
                Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter
                Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
            <Setter
                Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
            <Setter
                Property="Padding"
                Value="1,0,0,0" />
            <Setter
                Property="Foreground"
                Value="{StaticResource {x:Static 
                SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter
                Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}" />
            <Setter
                Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate
                        TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition
                                    MinWidth="19"
                                    Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition
                                    Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition
                                    Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition
                                    Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <WrapPanel
                                Grid.Column='0'>
                                <CheckBox />
                                <ToggleButton
                                    x:Name="Expander"
                                    Style="{StaticResource 
                                    ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                    TemplatedParent}}"
                                    ClickMode="Press" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                            <Border
                                Name="Bd"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding 
                                BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    x:Name="PART_Header"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding 
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsPresenter
                                x:Name="ItemsHost"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger
                                Property="IsExpanded"
                                Value="false">
                                <Setter
                                    TargetName="ItemsHost"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger
                                Property="HasItems"
                                Value="false">
                                <Setter
                                    TargetName="Expander"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Hidden" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition
                                        Property="HasHeader"
                                        Value="false" />
                                    <Condition
                                        Property="Width"
                                        Value="Auto" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter
                                    TargetName="PART_Header"
                                    Property="MinWidth"
                                    Value="75" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition
                                        Property="HasHeader"
                                        Value="false" />
                                    <Condition
                                        Property="Height"
                                        Value="Auto" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter
                                    TargetName="PART_Header"
                                    Property="MinHeight"
                                    Value="19" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger
                                Property="IsSelected"
                                Value="true">
                                <Setter
                                    TargetName="Bd"
                                    Property="Background"
                                    Value="AliceBlue" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition
                                        Property="IsSelected"
                                        Value="true" />
                                    <Condition
                                        Property="IsSelectionActive"
                                        Value="false" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter
                                    TargetName="Bd"
                                    Property="Background"
                                    Value="{StaticResource {x:Static 
                                    SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter
                                    Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{StaticResource {x:Static 
                                    SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger
                                Property="IsEnabled"
                                Value="false">
                                <Setter
                                    Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{StaticResource {x:Static 
                                    SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem
            Style='{StaticResource CheckboxTreeItem}'
            Header='Item'
            IsExpanded='True'>
            <TreeViewItem
                Style='{StaticResource CheckboxTreeItem}'
                Header='SubItem 1' />
            <TreeViewItem
                Style='{StaticResource CheckboxTreeItem}'
                Header='SubItem 2'>
                <TreeViewItem
                    Style='{StaticResource CheckboxTreeItem}'
                    Header='SubItem a' />
                <TreeViewItem
                    Style='{StaticResource CheckboxTreeItem}'
                    Header='SubItem b' />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for example.
You understand what I mean. Now we have root element Header='Item'
and near checkbox - it's good, but next item Header='SubItem 1' has offset - it's ok too. But checkbox of Header='SubItem 1' has to stay under checkbox root, not has offset.

Comment: Could you give me revised version?

Comment: If you want the TreeViewItems indented, but all of the checkboxes flush left (no matter their indent) then you may need to add some way of knowing your nesting level.  I'm unsure of how to accomplish this in Xaml alone.

Comment: Do you mean I need some Converters?

Comment: A converter may work, where you take as input an ancestor's margin and move over that much plus some fixed amount.  Honestly, I don't know how to solve this off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the header of your TreeViewItem to add a Checkbox to the left.  Here's a quick example to get you started, this xaml just adds a checkbox to the left and a TextBlock to the right.

```
<TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <CheckBox />
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin='5,0'
                        Text='Item' />
                </WrapPanel>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <CheckBox />
                        <TextBlock
                            Margin='5,0'
                            Text='SubItem' />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Depending on your scenario you may want to create a whole new template to override the default look for all TreeViewItems, if you do, then checkout the MSDN TreeViewItem Control Template example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788727.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I mean situation like this:

-----------------------------|

TreeView

Column1   Column2

CheckBox  TreeViewItem

CheckBox         TreeViewItem

CheckBox                TreeViewItem

 

All checkboxes have to be alignment on the left, treeview on the right side. Withou using LisBox or TreeListView

Comment: When I use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788727.aspx
I have situation when checkbox on the left side but not alignment in column.

Comment: What you want is for all checkboxes to be aligned underneath eachother along the left, regardless of nesting depth for the TreeViewItem.  I'm nearly certain this is doable using the ControlTemplate, but it's been a while since I've looked into it.  I'll see if I can find it and post some code.

Comment: I want like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771523.aspx
But without ListBox and TreeListView.
On the left checkboxes, in next column treeview (main). CheckBox is the same treeviewitem from main treeview.